# Using of graphql service within desktop application that "follows" MVVM and DDD

Tags: wpf, mvvm, graphql, domain-driven-design, desktop-application

We have a WPF desktop application that uses MVVM pattern and DDD (well, let's say that at least my model classes that store data named by entities taken from  the real world). APP uses several microservices through REST API. And it worked perfectly. Until we thought that it's time to use some facade for back-end part to unite all those microservices and get only data that we need for particular screen.

---

BUT. The question is, how to make them live together.

- On the one hand, we have dynamically returned data from graphql. It
  means that, for example, if we have list of people on the one screen,
  we will request id, name, surname and role of the person. On the
  different screen for dropdown of people we will request the same data
  but without role.
- On the other hand we have class Person that has static set of fields Name, Surname, **Role** and Id, which person has in "real life"

If we use the same Person class with graphql, **converting data from JSON** to model Person, both screens will work fine, but behind the scene one screen that doesn't need Role *wouldn't request it from graphQL*. And we will have a situation when model class Person will have field Role but it will be just empty (which is i believe is kind of smells. *At least I don't feel like it would be easy to maintain such a code. Developer needs to add some information to the screen, opens model, sees that Role is there, bind the field to the screen and goes to drink cofee. And then oops, there is the fields but there was no data assigned* ).

---

Two variants I have on my mind are:

- either to not use models and DDD and map data directly to ViewModel
  (which personally feels like ruining everything we had before).
- or we map that dynamic data to our existing models and different field for different screens (for the same class Person e.g.) will be
  empty (because not requested).

---

Maybe somebody has already used such a combination. How do you use it and what pros and cons are?

Comment: You can still use DDD value objects for query parameters and response fields. It will work well for query validation and building/parsing DB queries. DDD entities are more about mutations than queries, though. Queries (not only GraphQL) are much more diverse and though they should use ubiquitous language, it is still only a part of them.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly common situation where you have a data layer returns many columns but only some are used in a given view.

There is no absolute "best" solution independent of how much impact the full set of columns will have on performance.  Which might in turn be linked to things like caching.

You could write services that return subsets of data and then you only use the necessary bandwidth. Sort of a CQRS pattern but with maybe more models than just read + write.

Often this is unnecessary and the complications introduced do not compensate for the increased cost of maintenance.

What is often done is just to map from model to viewmodel (and back). The viewmodel that needs just 4 columns just has 4 properties and any more returned by the model are not copied.  The viewmodel that needs 5 has 5 properties and they are copied from the model.